# Why do we use 'strlen()' if 'printf()' itself returns the length of the string?

Tags: c, printf, string-length, strlen

The C function `printf()` returns the no of characters printed then what makes `strlen()` different?

Comment: Eh, because strlen() returns the length of the string without printing it? BTW: Please learn [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *"Cutting the chicken open with a knife also gets us the egg, why don't we do that instead of having it lay the egg?"* – Err, because one has side effects, and the other doesn't…?

Comment: Well, thank you. Fine explanation for a newbie. But I never thought that the community is so negative about beginners. I cannot ask more questions from this account now :-(

Answer (score 3):

As bub said, part of the difference is that `strlen` doesn't print the string, just returns its length. Also, though, printf() interprets its argument as a format string - what it ends up printing can be a very different length from the string it was given if it inserts values into placeholders.

Comment: Although the question is terribly imprecise, it is only fair to point out that `strlen(s)` and `printf("%s", s)` will return the same value as long as there is no problem with `stdin`. The assumption that OP intended to use `printf` incorrectly is not based on anything written in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` function calculates the length of string. Thats it for `strlen` but `printf()` sends formatted output.